# Cron job is not working when I add log options

Tags: cron

I have a cron job to execute a file upload to GCP storage. I am able to run the  script is working fine.

When I changed it to a cron job it stops working.

```
*/5 * * * *  (eval mydate=`date +\%m\%d\%Y` ; /home/script/uploadFile.sh dev | tee -a /home/script/upload_log_$mydate)
```

It is creating an empty log file and file upload is not happening.

Comment: Add a line `SHELL=/bin/bash` somewhere near the top of your crontab file.